# Android/OpenGLES2 - Create "shader' program in different thread

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm new to OpenGLES and I've got a problem with shader programs.
My scenario is:

```
Thread A(works as loop) manages everything but it does not draw on screen
Thread B only draws on screen
Thread A decides if Thread B will draw in current cycle
```

My problem is when Thread A creates shader program for Thread B, B cannot access attribs and uniform locations

This is how A creates shader program:

```
int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, pixelShader);
GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
```

This is how Thread B uses program:

```
GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
int positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
```

glGetAttribLocation returns -1 if mProgram was created by Thread A
glGetAttribLocation returns valid location when mProgram was created by Thread B

If Thread A created mProgram and positionHandle is hardcoded to valid location shader program does not work eather.

My question: Is it possible to create shader program in Thread A to be usable by Thread B?

Comment: You can have only one rendering context active at a time and it cannot be used from a different thread. You should read this: http://www.equalizergraphics.com/documentation/parallelOpenGLFAQ.html#.UBWq0bQlVTI

However, I am unable to find a makecurrent alternative for GLES20. It could very well be that it does not exist. I would advice to just call the OpenGL commands in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your whole question; I've only read "your scenario". And since you say you are new to OpenGL/GameDev, I'll simply say that your "scenario" is wrong. A long time ago, my first game I wrote also used a similar approach, so I don't blame you :).

You should be using a single thread that works like this:

```
load everything (textures, shaders, buffers, ...)
while (running)
{
    start timer
    update game (step by one frame, handle user input)
    render game
    show to openglbuffer to the screen (swap buffers)
    stop timer
    manage fps limiting (ie: sleep, using the difference of the timers)
}
clean up
```

The reason for all the problems with OpenGL you have, is that only one thread can have the OpenGL context.

Comment: I've got experience in GameDev(directX) and multi threating so it's not the problem.
My problem is shader programs, and since I know that OpenGL works as state machine and I'm 100% sure that when Thread A creates shader programs Thread B does nothing, I should be able to create valid shader program

Comment: Maybe, you misunderstood my sentence, but only one **fixed** thread has the context. But I think it should be possible to change it manually. http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_context

Comment: DirectX works in a totally different way to OGL. versions of DX work different from each other, so you definitively have to take that into account. It looks to me that you are trying to do double buffering, there is a proper OGL way to do that (google it).

Comment: Unfortunately, the behaviour of OpenGL contexts in multithreaded programs isn't well-specified - and often driver-dependent. Nvidia's OpenGL driver, for example, is known to instantiate thread-specific data for contexts, which means any given context can only be used from within the thread that created it. Other drivers don't behave that way (and contexts can be "passed" between threads). Still, the only _portable_ way is to make sure that only the thread that creates an OpenGL context is using it.